# Confused about how git branches work

Tags: git

I'm trying out git with a Rails app. I created a new branch for a feature, messed it up and now want to start over from the master branch. So I `git checkout master`, a branch I left before I had any work done in the new feature branch.

From what I read, I was under the impression that by doing this I would now be working in my app as it was in the last commit before the new branch, but all the files are still the same as it was in the new branch I was just working on. The new feature model, controller, migration etc, everything is still there. I didn't even commit the last changes in the new branch, but they still show up in the files that I thought were supposed to be from the previous `master` state.

Is my git installation malfunctioning or am I missing something? How exactly do I get back to working on the state I had before creating the new branch? Reading the docs I can't figure out where I went wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you switch between branches, any uncommitted changes you've made will be transferred over between each `checkout`. This is desired `git` behaviour - usually you'll start working on a quick feature in `master`, realize it should get its own feature branch, then make a new branch with `git checkout -b my-new-branch`, which will bring over anything you've worked on so far without committing it yet.

There is some safeguarding here when, for example, there's a change in `master` that would affect your uncommitted changes when you switch back to the master branch (the "you have unsaved changes that would be overwritten - please `git stash`" message.)

To fix this, assuming you truly don't want to keep any of your work, simply do `git checkout -- .` while you're in the `master` branch and all of your changes will go away.

If you'd like to keep your work, go back to the branch you've made, add and commit the files, then switch back to `master`. You will find it will be in its proper state then.

As for the [official docs](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout):

> To prepare for working on `<branch>`, switch to it by updating the index and the files in the working tree, and by pointing HEAD at the branch. **Local modifications to the files in the working tree are kept, so that they can be committed to the `<branch>`.**

and for my explanation about the safeguard that I described above (found under the `--merge-` option:

> When switching branches, if you have local modifications to one or more files that are different between the current branch and the branch to which you are switching, the command refuses to switch branches in order to preserve your modifications in context.